# Set Emoji size programmatically in com.rockerhieu.emojicon library

Tags: android, android-custom-view, attr

actually I am using Emojicon library in my sample project.. in this library we are setting custom textView in xml like:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:emojicon="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconTextView
          android:id="@+id/TextWithEmoji"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:textColor="@android:color/black"
          emojicon:emojiconSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and it is setting **emojicon:emojiconSize as 25sp**.. but the problem is I have to set my textSize programmatically.. I can do that using TextWithEmoji.setTextSize(xx.xxF)..

but the problem is I don't know how to set **emojicon:emojiconSize** programmatically to match the textSize..

Comment: emojis are image so you have to give size in dp instead of sp.

Comment: `I have to set my textSize programatically` **why**?

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way first thing that i have saw in your xml you are not setting the orientation as well as the orientation of the layout too kindly try in this way

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
```

you donot give the height and width as well as orientation to your parent linear layout

Comment: I'm using that.. the thing is I have added <LinearLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:emojicon="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" > because it is important..

Comment: can you help me in how to set custom class parameters like emojicon:emojiconSize programatacally.?

Comment: what I just want to do is when I set the text size programatically, I also set the emojicon:emojiconSize this size with it..